# Explanation about multiple su

Tags: linux, unix, pid, su

I'm a bit confused when a multiple su happen. Lets say a situation like this happen:

```
Fikrie su to root :

ps -ef | grep su:

root       15524  15388  0  10:15  pts/0  00:00:00 su root
```

I know that the pid for that su is 15524 and the parent pid is 15388. But when a multiple su happen. eg : this situation.

```
Fikrie su root:
root su fikrie2:
fikrie 2 su root:

ps -ef | grep su:

root       15450  15388  0  10:15  pts/0  00:00:00 su root
fikrie2    15468  15458  0  10:15  pts/0  00:00:00 su fikrie2
root       15478  15476  0  10:15  pts/0  00:00:00 su root
```

I thought that when root su into fikrie2, the first pid will be the ppid for the second su. Somehow when I tried to grep the process, this confuses me. The ppid became `15458` instead of `15450` or `15388`. None of the ppid are connected/related to the ppid or pid before it. I tried to google and read about `process relationship` in `Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment` book. Can someone give me a good explanation about this or maybe a link to help me understand more on the process relationship.

I'm trying to write a code to find the user that su into that user. From all the answer I look into SO, they only help to find the original user, eg. fikrie. If the second situation happen, I wasn't able to get fikrie2 when I su to root from fikrie2. Instead I get fikrie which is the original user. My original idea was to use the parent id to get the user, but when doing it from command line. This really confuse me.

PS* I'm trying this on Unix platform. I do not know anything about Windows, but if the ppid and pid are different between Windows and Unix, please point me the direction into Unix.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I suspect that the parent process that you are seeing is the shell which got called.  When you su you will run the .profile which will call multiple other processes and will end with a shell being launched.  So the parent process isn't going to be the previous invocation of su, because that isn't the process which spawned this one.  The shell did that.